# WARNING: ext4 signature detected on /dev/VG/swap at offset 1080. Wipe it?

Tags: lvm

I have created a VG, and want to create a LV for swap:

```
$ sudo lvcreate -n swap -L 4G VG
WARNING: ext4 signature detected on /dev/VG/swap at offset 1080. Wipe it? [y/n]: y
  Wiping ext4 signature on /dev/VG/swap.
  Logical volume "swap" created.
$ sudo lvcreate -n root -L 40G VG
  Logical volume "root" created.
$ sudo lvcreate -n home -l 100%FREE VG
  Logical volume "home" created.
```

What does that warning mean? What shall I do about it?

Why do the following two commands not have the warning?

Thanks.

Comment: You... already did something about it, according to the "y" response to "wipe it?"

Comment: Which word you don't understand about the warning message?

Comment: Every single concept in the message.

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477991/what-is-a-vfat-signature/478001#478001

Answer (score 11):

## What does that warning mean?

The warning means that once upon a time, there was an ext4 filesystem in the same disk location (start offset) as the swap partition you were trying to create.

NOTICE: When you delete a partition, the filesystem within does not get deleted.

The warning exists to give you a chance to back out of the irreversible operation, in case you selected the block device.

## What shall I do about it?

You already did something about it. You wiped it.

## Why do the following two commands not have the warning?

The following two commands did not have the warning because no previous filesystem was detected at those disk locations.

Comment: If I don't wipe it, will I automatically restore the old drive, that was sitting there "once upon a time"?

Comment: Not exactly, rubo77. That warning only means that once upon a time, an ext4 filesystem was created *starting* at that location. It makes no guarantees about the integrity of the entire filesystem. `testdisk` is a utility you can use to attempt to restore a filesystem.