# lvm: dos signature detected on /dev/sda4 at offset 510. Wipe it?

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm trying to dual boot Arch Linux (on LVM) and Windows 10 (which I upgraded from Windows 7) on my BIOS/MBR system. I made a Linux LVM partition (it's name is `/dev/sda4`) with fdisk, but when I try to enter

```
# pvcreate /dev/sda4
```

I get the following message:

```
WARNING: dos signature detected on /dev/sda4 at offset 510. Wipe it? [y/n]
```

What are the consequences of entering `y`? Is it going to affect my Windows installation?

Comment: Please add `fdisk -l /dev/sda` to your question

Comment: please post the output of `sudo file -s /dev/sda4` - looks like you have a Windows partition on it.

Comment: if you've had a FAT file system on this area of the disk it could just be that pvcreate is picking up the signature and asking for conformation ahead of letting it be wiped eventually as the PV is used.

Comment: My sincere apologies to everyone since I should have researched thoroughly before asking this question... After checking out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502605/warning-ext4-signature-detected-on-dev-vg-swap-at-offset-1080-wipe-it/502624 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477991/what-is-a-vfat-signature/478001#478001 I realized that necessary to enter `y` in order to use `pvcreate`.